# Find the smallest number of students for which the probability of a birthday duplicate is at least 0.5

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Easiest way to approach this problem without dealing with nasty factorials

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Already asked on the site, perhaps even as many times as the answer (23).

Comment: Deal with nice factorials instead.

Comment: I don't think it was fair to mark this question as a duplicate. adam asked for a solution without factorials, which the "duplicate" question does not. This was clearly not a useless question, as I presented a solution which uses no factorials. Unfortunately I do not have the reputation to cast a re-open vote...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a year has $n$ days. Now if we have $k$ people in a room the probability no two people  have the same birthday is:
$$ p = \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left ( 1 - \frac{i-1}{n} \right ) \ge \prod_{i=1}^{k} e^{\frac{-i+1}{n}} = \text{exp} \left ( \frac{k(k-1)}{2n} \right )$$

So we need roughly $\sqrt{2n \ln 2}$ people. This is pretty accurate for large $n$, as then our approximations get closer and closer to correct.

Comment: Can I know what this formula is called? I'd like to see the proof of it to understand it better thanks

Comment: @adam See the comments about the Birthday Problem.